# singular matrix in numerical

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant

I am trying to find all values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for which

$$ A(\alpha, \beta)= 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
3&0&-2\\\alpha&3&2\\-2&2&\beta 
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

is singular.

My understanding is that I need to find values $\beta$ and $\alpha$ for which $det(A)=0$

Therefore so,

$$\det(A) = 3
\begin{bmatrix}
3&2\\2&\beta
\end{bmatrix} - 0 + (-2)\left[
\begin{matrix}
\alpha&3\\-2&2
\end{matrix}
\right]\\= 3(3\beta - 4) - 2(2\alpha +6) \\ = 9\beta -12 -4\alpha -12$$

If my workings are correct, then what is $\beta,\alpha?$

Comment: Are $\alpha,\beta$ integers?

Comment: it does not clarify in the question

Comment: Well, if they don't have to be integers, then there are lots of solutions. Just take $a=\frac{9}{4}b-6$.

Comment: Simply solve $9\beta -12 -4\alpha -12=0$.

Comment: could I just take one of them to be $0$?

Comment: I've removed [tag:numerical-methods] since all values are exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. But there is no unique answer.

For each $\alpha $ and $\beta$ such that $9\beta -4\alpha =24$ the matrix is singular.

So for each $\alpha $ you take, you can calculate $\beta $ (it is a linear function of $\alpha$): $$\beta = {4\over 9}\alpha +{8\over 3}$$

---

If those are integer then we have some more restriction, say $4∣β$ and $3∣α$:

**Proof:**  $$9\beta =4\alpha +24 = 4(\alpha+6)\implies 4\mid 9\beta \implies 4\mid \beta $$ so $\beta =4y$. Now we have $$9y-\alpha =6 \implies 3(3y-2)=\alpha \implies 3\mid \alpha$$ So $\alpha = 3x$. So, $x$ and $y$ are connected with formula $3y-x=2$ and now however you choose integer $y$ you can calculate integer $x$ (by again linear formula) $$ x= 3y-2$$

Comment: is this if $\alpha, \beta $ are only integers?

Comment: so for every value of $\beta$ you can find $\alpha?$

Comment: and that's if $\beta$ and $\alpha$ $\in$ R?

Comment: okay thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you further explain if they are integer? It is a little confusing

Comment: why did you use 4|b and 3|alpha   why did you use the absolute value symbol?

Comment: Those are not absolute value, it is a sign wich denote divisibility. If I write $7\mid n$ it means that $n$ is divisible with 7

Answer (score 1):

You want $\det(A)=0$, so you have to solve the linear diophantine equation
$$9b-4a=24\tag{1}$$
We should first find a solution to the linear diophantine equation
$$9b-4a=1$$
which we can easily see is solved by $(a,b)=(2,1)$. Thus, we have that $(a,b)=(48,24)$ solves $(1)$, and by [Bézout's Identity,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) we may parametrize all solutions as
$$(a,b)=(48+9t,24+4t)$$
where $t\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: There is no information that $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Comment: I actually don't know if they are integers! there is no clarification

Comment: @jh123 Well, it's much easier to solve if they aren't integers, and you should be able to do it if that is the case. This answer addresses the case in which they are both integers. Besides, you really shouldn't ask a question unless you know what the question *is.*

Comment: it didn't clarify but I will have to find out

Comment: Why is the second equation equal to 1?

Comment: @jh123 That's a technique used when solving linear diophantine equations of that form. To find a particular solution to $9b-4a=24$, one may find $a',b'$ satisfying $9b'-4a'=1$ and then multiply both sides by $24$.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help I will study up on that technique

Comment: @jh123 No problem! If this was helpful, don't forget to $\uparrow$ and $\checkmark$! :)